# unable to build gradle in jenkins, Could not create service of type

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

When I try to do Build Android-studio project in jenkins I get this error:
Could not create service of type FileCollectionSnapshotterRegistry using TaskExecutionServices.createFileCollectionSnapshotterRegistry().

> Could not create service of type CachingFileHasher using TaskExecutionServices.createFileSnapshotter().

I didn't found a answer any place, please help me :)

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/AndroidProject
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/ShiraOzeri/Try_MyTest # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/ShiraOzeri/Try_MyTest
> git --version # timeout=10
> git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/ShiraOzeri/Try_MyTest +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 78a492d135b437ee188d71ba44a060540fc56a95 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f 78a492d135b437ee188d71ba44a060540fc56a95
> git rev-list 78a492d135b437ee188d71ba44a060540fc56a95 # timeout=10
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[AndroidProject] $ /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/AndroidProject/gradlew build
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type FileCollectionSnapshotterRegistry using TaskExecutionServices.createFileCollectionSnapshotterRegistry().
> Could not create service of type CachingFileHasher using TaskExecutionServices.createFileSnapshotter().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.083 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/AndroidProject/build/android-profile/profile-2017-06-19-18-24-07-215.rawproto

* Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

So. my solution:
first, you need to check if you have gradle

To test the Gradle installation, just run Gradle from the command-line:

```
gradle
```

second, this help me a lot,
try this:

```
chown -R jenkins:jenkins <Path to your jenkins>
```

example: chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/

Thanks!!

Comment: Does [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/v3-2-1-wrong-working-directory-could-not-create-service-of-type-taskhistorystore-using-taskexecutionservices-createcacheaccess/21011/2), you shoul also add `--no-daemon` to the `gradlew` command see if one of those help

Comment: @IdoSorozon Thank you! You helped me a lot! problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You can see it clearly in the error "AccessDeniedException"

> - What went wrong:
>     java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/AndroidProject/build/android-profile/profile-2017-06-19-18-24-07-215.rawproto

You probably have a user/group permissions problem. Try to see if the Jenkins user have permissions to make changes in that folder (since Jenkins has different user).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Seems like some process is holding the lock for it.

I tried removing the `taskArtifacts` from `.gradle` folder in the workspace but that didn't work.

Ultimately, just a restart of Android Studio did the trick!

Note: I didn't try the `chown` command as mentioned in the original question.