# Jenkins on Ubuntu, gradle fails on premission denied

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, gradle

I have a simple JenkinsFile that I'm running through Jenkins v2.121.3 on Ubuntu v18.04.1 LTS:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    // Run on a build agent where we have the Android SDK installed
    label 'android'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Compile') {
      steps {
        // Compile the app and its dependencies
        sh './gradlew compileProdDebugSources'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run my Jenkins job, it fails when running `+ ./gradlew compileProdDebugSources`:

> Could not create service of type TaskHistoryRepository using TaskExecutionServices.createTaskHistoryRepository().
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/.gradle/4.5/taskHistory/taskHistory.lock (Permission denied)

What's the right way to grant Jenkins permissions to access this file and other files it needs to use?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44645882/1531971

Comment: @jdv thanks. How can I determine which user Jenkins is using?

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/q/6692330/1531971 gives you what you need. My Jenkins box is Windows, so I'm not going to inflict what I know about that on you!